How to Replace Placeholders in a DOCX File with Flutter without Server-Side Processing?
I am trying to programmatically replace placeholders in a DOCX file with specific text using Flutter, without relying on any server-side processing. I need to update the placeholder {name} with the text "Deepak Kumar" directly within a Flutter application.
my docs look like below
enter image description here
I've experimented with the docx_template package to manipulate DOCX files, but continue to encounter errors and limitations. I've considered using flutter_quill for editing, but it does not support direct DOCX manipulations. I am looking for a Flutter-only solution that doesn't involve server-side processing.
Here's a simplified version of my Flutter code attempting to manipulate a DOCX file:
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:docx_template/docx_template.dart';

void _loadAndDisplayDocx() async {
  try {
    final ByteData? data = await rootBundle.load('assets/docs/template.docx');
    if (data == null) {
      debugPrint("Failed to load the DOCX file.");
      return;
    }

    final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    if (bytes.isEmpty) {
      debugPrint("DOCX file is empty after loading.");
      return;
    }

    final DocxTemplate docx = await DocxTemplate.fromBytes(bytes);
    if (docx == null) {
      debugPrint("Failed to initialize the DOCX template.");
      return;
    }

    final Content content = Content()..add(TextContent("name", "Deepak Kumar"));
    final List<int>? docGenerated = await docx.generate(content);
    if (docGenerated == null) {
      debugPrint("Failed to generate the document.");
      return;
    }

    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final File file = File('${directory.path}/output.docx');
    await file.writeAsBytes(docGenerated);
    final String? openResult = await OpenFile.open(file.path);
    if (openResult != "done") {
      debugPrint("Failed to open the document: $openResult");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint("Error generating or opening document: $e");
  }
}


error i got
Error generating or opening document: Null check operator used on a null value
